# Number of fingers of a Martian

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility, quadratics

I have a question about what seems to be modular arithmetic, but I can't quite get the answer.

The problem goes along the lines of:
It is often said Earthlings use the decimal system because they have ten fingers. We see a Martian write down the equation:

$$
x^2 - 19x + 76 = 0
$$

When asked to write down the difference between the larger and smaller root, the Martian writes 9. How many fingers do Martians have?
Note: Martians write numbers between 0 and 9 exactly as we do.

Comment: Did you know: Not all human languages use base 10. For example, there's a rare language somewhere that uses base 8; apparently, they were counting on the spaces _between_ the fingers rather than counting on the fingers themselves. (Also, you might have heard that the Mayans had base 20 and the Babylonians had base 60.

Comment: @columbus8myhw For completeness: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal#By_Native_Americans

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be the roots of the polynomial ($x_1 > x_2$) and let $b$ be the base martians use. Then:

$(x-x_1)(x-x_2) = x^2 - (x_1 + x_2) x + x_1\cdot x_2 = x^2 - 19_bx + 76_b$

And knowing that $x_1 - x_2 = 9$ then

$$\begin{cases}
x_1 - x_2 = 9 & \\
x_1 + x_2 = 1\cdot b + 9 & \\
x_1\cdot x_2 = 7\cdot b + 6 & \\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I don't get it: we have that  $\;x_1x_2=76\;$ . In base $\;b=6\;$ this is written $\;204\;$ , so why do you think it can be written as you wrote? Also, if $\;b=24\;$ , then $\;76=34_{24}\;$, again not the form you gave. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Timbuc Both $19$ and $76$ are already written in base $b$.

Comment: Exactly my point:  $\;x_1x_2=76\;$ in decimal basis as we do, so why do you think that in basis $\;b\;$ that'd be $\;7b+6\;$ ?

Comment: @Timbuc The Martians were the ones who wrote the $76$ in the first place. Doesn't that mean it was written in base $b$?

Comment: Well, that's true and now I understand better the comment by Darth. Thank you both! I still can't  see the solution, though...but now I think I know better what direction to take.

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$x^2 - (b + 9)x + 7b + 6 = 0 \Rightarrow x_1 - x_2 = 2\sqrt{(\frac{b+9}{2})^2-7b - 6} = 9$

We can rearrange  little:

$(\frac{b+9}{2})^2-7b - 6 = \frac{81}{4}$

$(b+9)^2-28b - 24 = 81$

$b^2 + 18b + 81 -28b - 24 = 81$

$b^2 -10b - 24 = 0$

$b_{12} = 5 \pm \sqrt{5^2 + 24} = 5 \pm 7 \Rightarrow b = 12$

So martians can be assumed to have a dirty dozen of green fingers!

Answer (score 0):

Call the roots $x_1$ and $x_2$. If $x_1-x_2=9$, we must have:
$$(x_1-x_2)^2=81_{10}$$
Or, in other words:
$$(x_1+x_2)^2-4x_1x_2=81_{10}$$
Using Viete, we have:
$$19_b^2-4\times76_b=81_{10}$$
Could that help?

Comment: But then how do I know b from the last equation? Thanks!

Comment: @Isaacs Perhaps you should expand $19_b$ into $b+9$, and expand $76_b$ into $7b+6$. After expanding, I think you'll get a quadratic in $b$.

Comment: @Timbuc The solution ends up being $<19$ anyway.

Comment: @columbus8myhw I see that now thanks to your *other* comment: as the martian wrote $\;76\;$ , it **must** mean $\;7b+6\;$ in their base $\;b\;$ ...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question.

The equation:

$x^2-19x+76=0$

In our world, the roots for this equation are

$$\frac{19 \pm \sqrt77}{2}$$

Difference : $\sqrt 77$

This same difference is 9 in his world, on a different base.

So, we can apply base conversion rules here.

$$\sqrt77_{10}=9_b$$

$$\log_{10}\sqrt77=\log_b9$$

$$\log_{10}\sqrt77=\frac{\log_{10}9}{\log_{10}b}$$

The answer, however comes out to be $10.25$ which is quite strange.